# Rows to Columns and viceversa in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I am very new to sql and I need a better approach for the below scenario.

Table

[image]

And I need to convert to below result.

[image]

Comment: Do a UNION ALL, one select per col1 - col4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using unpivot. Here is the sample demo with data.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
        ID INT
        ,COL1 VARCHAR(3)
        ,COL2 VARCHAR(3)
        ,COL3 VARCHAR(3)
        ,COL4 VARCHAR(3)
        )
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES

(1,'yes',null,'yes',null)
,(2,null,'yes',null,'yes')
,(3,null,null,'yes',null)
,(4,null,null,null,null)
,(5,null,'yes','yes',null)
,(6,null,null,null,null)
,(7,null,null,null,'yes')


SELECT id
    ,yes
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,col1
        ,col2
        ,col3
        ,col4
    FROM @TABLE
     where coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4) is not null
    ) AS cp
UNPIVOT(yes FOR col IN (
            col1
            ,col2
            ,col3
            ,col4
            )) AS up
union
select id, null from @TABLE
    where coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4) is null
order by id
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a `UNION ALL`, one select for each col*n*, and finally one SELECT for rows without any yes at all.

```
select id, 'col1' from tablename where col1 = 'yes'
union all
select id, 'col2' from tablename where col2 = 'yes'
union all
select id, 'col3' from tablename where col3 = 'yes'
union all
select id, 'col4' from tablename where col4 = 'yes'
union all
select id, cast(null as char(4)) from tablename
    where 'yes' not in (coalesce(col1, 'x'),
                        coalesce(col2, 'x'),
                        coalesce(col3, 'x'),
                        coalesce(col4, 'x'))
```

If the only value is 'yes' (or NULL), then the last select can be done as

```
select id, cast(null as char(4)) from tablename
where coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4) is null
```

Comment: What about NULL values in col1, col2, etc.? Wouldn't `NOT IN (col1, col2..)` cause problems?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, oops, shame on me... You are absolutely right. Will edit.

Comment: You can use a simple `where coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4, 'no') = 'no'`

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, could be done like that, but what if another value <> yes shows up later?

Comment: @sagi, most dbms products don't need that `cast`, but some do - and ANSI SQL requires it. (I don't know about MS SQL Server.)

Comment: `tablename` is a intermediate table created from many subqueries and case statements. in that case, how to frame this query @jarlh

Comment: for ex: `select id, 'col1' from (many queries and case statements) AS tablename where col1 = 'yes'` for every select statement, the query will grow bigger right

Comment: Easy way is to put that "(many queries and case statements)" as a cte (common table expression.) However, it could be better to re-write the whole query. Hard to say without even seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do it as the below.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
       B.ID, 
       B.yes,
       B.col
    FROM 
        (SELECT ID ,
                ISNULL(COL1, '') COL1 ,
                ISNULL(COL2, '') COL2,
                ISNULL(COL3, '') COL3 ,
                ISNULL(COL4, '') COL4
            FROM @Tbl) A
    UNPIVOT
    (
      col
      FOR yes in (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    ) B
) 


SELECT CTE.ID, CTE.yes FROM  CTE
WHERE  col = 'yes'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT  ID, '' FROM CTE A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM CTE B WHERE 
        B.ID = A.ID AND
        B.col = 'yes'
)
```

Result:

```
ID          yes  
----------- -----
1           COL1
1           COL3
2           COL2
2           COL4
3           COL3
4           
5           COL2
5           COL3
6           
7           COL4
```

Comment: This will exclude rows with 'yes' values.